# Recover deleted azure databricks workspace

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I deleted by mistake an azure databricks workspace which is not integrated with git. How can we recover the deleted workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Users cannot directly recover the deleted Azure Databricks workspace.

This can be done via backend engineers by opening a technical support ticket.

Note: Make sure to raise a technical support ticket asap.

[image]

How to [create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).